# Entity Framework code first create a superclass in two existing classes,

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-6

This is my first time here so sorry if I did not put the doubt by default. In my project I have two models class **doubts** and a class of **works**, I want to create a **classification** for both using a superclass, like the design pattern strategy. But I have a problem, the project state is advanced and I have used the doubt and works classes many times. Already tried in many ways, but either the error in the update-database or the error in what I had done before.
**Does anyone know one way that I can implement a generic class classification for the doubts and works classes without many changes of what I had already done?**

My code is below

```
public abstract class Classificable
{

    [Key]
    public int id { get; set; }
    public virtual Classification classication { get; set; }
}

public class Doubt : Classificable
{

    public int doubtID { get; set; }
    public string question { get; set; }
    public string content { get; set; }

    public virtual Student student { get; set; }
    public virtual Course course { get; set; }
    public virtual Work work { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Answer> answers { get; set; }
}

public class Work : Classificable 
{

    public int workID { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string nameWork { get; set; }
    public string filePath { get; set; }

    public virtual Student student { get; set; }
    public virtual Course course { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Doubt> doubts { get; set; }
}

public class DB_DIS : DbContext
{

    public DB_DIS()
        : base("name=DB_DIS")
    {
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Doubt>().ToTable("Doubts");
        modelBuilder.Entity<Work>().ToTable("Works");

    }


    public virtual DbSet<Doubt> Doubts { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<Work> Works { get; set; }
}`
```

Comment: *I have used the doubt and works classes many times* Please explain what you mean by that. Also, tell *which* errors you get.

Comment: The name is not the most appropriate, but the goal is to use this comparable class to allow me to use a generic algorithm to classify doubts and works. But the big issue is that I didn't thought of this superclass before and I already have the database and a big part of the program and it's complicated to add this superclass .

Answer (score 0):

What is the property or method in `Classificable` that you are trying to apply to `Doubt` and `Work`?

Have you written your data structure in such a way that is contains an `id` field AND `workID` feild?

In my experience, if you are trying to share properties between EF Classes you are better off sharing common fields.  I've used it in the past for base classes of `AuditableBase` as follows:

```
public class AuditableBase
{
    public string UpdateUserId { get; set; }
    public DateTime UpdateDate { get; set; }
}
```

Then all my classes that I want to "Audit" will have a `UpdateUserId` and `UpdateDate`, and I can do some pre-save processing to set those based on the type of `AuditableBase`.

Comment: The name is not the most appropriate, but the goal is to use this comparable class to allow me use a generic algorithm to classify doubts and works

Comment: I think the problem is you have your key in the base class.  I think you need to move that out and put keys in `Work` and `Doubt`.  The error you are most likely getting is that EF cannot tell convert the underlying datareader to a `Work` object because your `Work` data storage doesn't have a key column named 'id'.  Take the key out and you should be able to refer to `Work` and `Doubt` as `Classificable`.

Comment: Yes I was able to do the update-database, now I'm going to try to adapt the classification method that I have done. Thank you very much